# Getting license error when running the command "Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr"

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect

When we are trying to run the command `Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr` in the `XC search indexer`, we are getting the license missing error.

We already placed the partner license which is already had the `Sitecore.xDB.Base license.`

Error:

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker>Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr
Requesting rebuild.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.LicenseException: Required license is missing: Sitecore.xDB.Base
   at ?????????????????????????????????????????.(????????????????????????????????????????? , String )
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.InitializeLicenseCheck(IServiceCollection collection, String licenseFileOrXml)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.UseXConnectServiceInitializationConfiguration(IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration configuration, String[] configurationSectionNames, String initializationSectionName, Boolean validateConfiguration)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.ServiceProviderFactory.GetDiServiceProvider(IConfiguration config, String modelDirectory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHostDependencies..ctor(IConfigurationRoot config)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.<UpdateRebuildStatus>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: can you check if this license is not the expired one? Usually, partner licenses expired around 30 Aug.

Answer (score 1):

When you update Sitecore license you have to update it in multiple places.

It's never easy to find all of them manually.

Luckily Robert Senktas wrote a powershell script that will do this for you.

You can find his article here: https://blog.senktas.net/2019/08/22/how-to-stop-sitecore-license-update-nightmare/

And the script goes like that:

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator 

# Update all licenses
# You can find more about automation with Powershell on http://lets-share.senktas.net

$iisRoot = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" 
$licenseFile = "C:\license.xml"

(Get-ChildItem -Path $iisRoot -Filter 'license.xml' -Recurse).DirectoryName | % { Copy-Item -Path $licenseFile -Destination $_ -Verbose}
```

You just set `$licenseFile` variable to the correct location of your new license and run that script as administrator. Script will update license in every place under "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".

Remember to restart IIS to make sure that Sitecore reloads licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path and open the license file.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[your Sitecore xConnect]\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\license.xml
```

Then search for this

```
<name>Sitecore.xDB.Base</name>
```

Under that, you will find the expiration date. You need to verify this.

```
<count>1</count>
<expiration>yourlicenseexpirationdate</expiration>
```

If that is expired then you need a new one.

Hope this helps.

Thanks